# Any good ways to get useful information when the released App has no response to User Interaction?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

**Background:**

I release my App on the App Store.
Now, some users reflect the problem: when they install the App and launch it, the App was blocked at the launching page, or some other pages.

**What I'm interested is that if there are some ways to detect the running function which blocks the UI thread.**

If I have the iPhone which meets the problem, maybe I can use Instruments to attach to the process, and find the time-consuming unit.

But I cannot always have the real iPhone. **Can I write some code in advance and when the problem occurs, I can write the Call Stack down to the log on disk**?

Many thanks.

Comment: does the app gets killed by watchdog? (aka does it crash!)

Comment: @ArianSharifian Sometimes it does, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: If I had to guess I would put my money on a network related problem. The app tries to download and parse a file, and if the app can't reach the server it'll wait sixty something seconds until the timeout, the timeout is not handled correctly and the app crashes because it tries to parse bogus data. I've fixed such bugs in client apps (they asked me to fix their apps) over and over again. Network stuff is probably number one reason for crashes during startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is some way to monitor you app in (near) realtime to know not just analytics but app crashes and other problems. In this area, there are some really good services which do the job for you.

1. [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com/mobile-monitoring) - mobile monitoring
2. [chartbeat](https://chartbeat.com/)
3. [testflight](https://testflightapp.com/)
4. [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) - as mentioned by @jszumski

I have tried all of them although their feature set is somewhat similar but they differ slightly. I prefer NewRelic mobile monitoring. Hope this helps...

Comment: It's a crime to not mention [Crashlytics](https://www.crashlytics.com/) when listing crash reporting services.

Comment: @SrikarAppal Oh, No. :) We've used Crashlytics or something else, but in the situation I told in the question, the user cannot launch the App, so the App cannot upload the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your application is doing some heavy weight stuff on the launch. Is is basically a bad habit. App should always bypass the launch phase before doing any large amount of work. That's why you see many apps have "Loading..." or "Please wait..." or an image with light animations etc at theire launch.
**Solution:**
Try watching [Up and Running: Making a Great Impression with Every Launch](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766) (Session 225) from WWDC 2012. This is one of the most useful sessions I've ever seen from WWDC. Try not to mess with watchdog!
Create your own logging mechanism. Write the time frame and a refrence to each line to a txt file. then on each launch if that file exists, on `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or even `main` grab that file and use one of the reporting solutions mentioned on other solutions and report it. If you actually have the device try using 
`NSLog(@"%@ happend", eventName)` 
and watch console for event logs.
Also I use [plcrashreporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/), it's free and open-source.
Hope this helps